# Puzzling java.lang.NullPointerException in Android App

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm currently working on an Android App and, almost every time I use it, I get a an error. Most of the time it doesn't crash the app, but it is still frustrating that I'm seeing this error. I thought I did a check for it, but I could be wrong. Thanks for the help! The relevant code is below. (It's relevant because the line outside the `if` statement is throwing the `NullPointerException`.)

```
 Activity activity;     

 if(activity == null)
 {
   activity = new Activity();
 }

 Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Service.class);
```

Comment: I think you forgot a semicolon inside the if statement.

Comment: That's no real code, that doesn't even compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post some more of the surrounding code, but your problem is that creating new `Intent` requires a valid `Context`. Usually you create an `Intent` within an `Activity` (or `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver`) class so you can just do something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
```

Occasionally you'll create it somewhere else and pass it that valid `Context`, but you should pretty much never create an `Activity` by calling the constructor directly. There's a lot of other initialization necessary to make it useful.

Comment: I hadn't originally been instantiating it that way, it's instantiated elsewhere, I'm just using `activity = new Activity()` as more of a check. It was throwing the null pointer exception, so I thought if I even gave it an empty activity, then it wouldn't throw that error anymore. I was obviously wrong, but I didn't think Service.class could be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You don't usually instantiate the Activity class in this manner. Please see the documentation on the Android Activity class here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

As postet previously there is more to initiate for an activity than calling the constructor. Probably you get a null pointer exception deep within the Intent Constructer where it is trying to get some of the Activityinformation usually provided.

If you really want to create a Service, heres a link for starting a Service, but you should really read the whole article and probably some more of the activity lifecycle ressources.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#StartingAService